KDE Spectacle exits fullscreen applications
I'm using kubuntu installed in stock ubuntu 22.04. Whenever I press the screenshot hotkey, Spectacle focuses on itself and exits out the fullscreen app. I've tried tinkering around in the settings, but could find nothing. Is there a way to stop this?

Just a personal observation I have never seen a screenshot app that does other then what you describe. I have always had to have the app a bit less then full screen to use such a tool.

Well, before I used kubuntu I was used to just pressing PrtSc and it taking a screenshot even in fullscreen. I was considering trying to just install the default GNOME one but I have no idea if that would break things or not, and I don't even know what it's called.
